# Is it possible to create a vertical bar in a table with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using Python to create `xlsx` files with `openpyxl` package. I have created simple table and I want to separate columns by a vertical bar. 
**Question**: How to create a vertical bar via `openpyxl`?

Comment: You can use style `border`, read about [OpenPyXL Working with styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html)

Comment: @stovfl, I found a solution where you pointed to. I think it would be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: How to create a vertical bar via openpyxl?

You can use style `border` or `fill`.

> [OpenPyXL Working with styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html) 
>   Styles are used to change the look of your data while displayed on screen. They are also used to determine the formatting for numbers.

For instance:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

data = [['A1', '', 'C1', '', 'E1'], ['A2', '', 'C2', '', 'E2'], ['A3', '', 'C3', '', 'E3'], ['A4', '', 'C4', '', 'E4']]
for row, rData in enumerate(data, 1):
    ws.append(rData)

from openpyxl.styles import Side, Border, PatternFill, Color
thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")
thin_white = Side(border_style="thin", color="FFFFFF")
border = Border(left=thin)
fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="666666")

from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
ws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 1
ws.column_dimensions['D'].width = 0.5
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries('B1:D4')
B = 0; D = 2
for row_cells in ws.iter_rows(min_col=min_col, min_row=min_row,
                                   max_col=max_col, max_row=max_row):

    row_cells[B].border = border
    row_cells[D].fill = fill
    row_cells[D].border = Border(left=thin_white, right=thin_white)

wb.save('../test/test.xlsx')
```

> **Output**: [image: Style Border and Fill]

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***